# HTML/CSS Li a hover after ul

Tags: html, css

I know how to display submenu. I need that `li` a home link, would be different color when my cursor is on submenu ... Hope you will understand what I am saying.

I Thought and tried that `#menu li a:hover >ul` but not working.

Sample of html menu:

```
<li><a href=# >home</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href=# >sub</a></li>
    <li><a href=# >sub</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: So you want to show the `ul` whenever you hover over an `a` tag?

Comment: You have several problems that you should fix and then clarify your question.
`ul` is the unordered-list, and `li` is the list-item, hence the `ul` should be the parent, and the `li`s the children. Also you need to close the `a` tags. Fix this and try to explain yourself again

Comment: fixed as you asked i was typing fast and haven't seen mistakes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/54evy99s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the parent `li`'s `:hover` pseudo class.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wf7w3h3p/)

**CSS:**

```
#homeMenu:hover #homeLink {
    color: blue;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li id="homeMenu">
        <a href="#" id="homeLink">home</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">sub</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">sub</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right way:

```
#menu li ul { display: none; }

#menu li:hover ul { display: block; }

#menu li > a { color: black; }

#menu li > a:hover { color: blue; }
```

Comment: I know how to display submenu. I need that li a home link would be different color when my cursor is on submenu

Comment: In this case you can only change the color when hovering the anchor itself. When you hover the submenu, the anchor would have it's default color again. No other option. I will adjust my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think this does what you want. Can't imagine how it would be useful, though.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" >home</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    display: none;
}
a:hover + ul{
    display: block;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hmvw4tjc/